# TCPDF write custom barcode in html template

Tags: php, symfony1, barcode, symfony-1.4, tcpdf

instead of type below in action.class.php :
$pdf->write1DBarcode('CODE 39', 'C39', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, '', 'N');

How can i make it custom so that i can write it in the template?

the reason is when i have to stamp the same barcode twice in one page...the normal barcode thing can only do it once in a page...please help me wth this...i kindly apreciated it..:D

Answer (score 0):

You can write TCPDF Methods in HTML as below

```
<?php
$params = $pdf->serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array('40144399300102444888207482244309', 'C128C', '', '', 0, 0, 0.2, array('position'=>'S', 'border'=>false, 'padding'=>4, 'fgcolor'=>array(0,0,0), 'bgcolor'=>array(255,255,255), 'text'=>false, 'font'=>'helvetica', 'fontsize'=>8, 'stretchtext'=>2), 'N'));    
$str='<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0">            
<tr> 
    <td align="left">barcode</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td align="center" style="padding-left:5px;">';
    $str .= '<tcpdf method="write1DBarcode" params="'.$params.'" />';
    $str .='</td>
</tr>
</table>';

$pdf->writeHTML($str,true, false,false,false,'left');
$pdf->Output('example_049.pdf', 'I');
?>
```

For detail reference please check TCPDF example_049.php